# Heroku why the domain doesn't show the changes I uploaded

Tags: heroku

Hello guys I have configure cloudfalre DNS to heroku, I uploaded a React app, but when I push new commits the domain does show the new changes
site : http://www.brahmakumaris-thessaloniki.gr/
heroku app : https://bkth.herokuapp.com/

Comment: A little more information would help, Did you integrate GitHub with your Heroku dynamo? Did you set an automatic deployment pipeline for a certain branch for your GitHub repository on Heroku?

Comment: Sorry for not providing the proper details, no I have not intergated GitHub to Heroku dynamo, although I should and I have not set an automatic deployment pipeline for the branch. The tutorial I watched just had be log in, create and push to heroku via the cli. Plz tell me what more info do you require